# Variable value not passing through loop

Tags: perl, variables, loops, conditional-statements

I have a loop that checks to see whether all the files in a directory are uploaded to the directory by checking to see if the number of files is constant.

Starting out, it knows that there are $before files in the directory ("before" it looks again).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $after = 0;
my $before ="10";

until($before == $after) {
    #check again, which changes the value of $after.
    #Now....
    $after = "20"; 

    if ( $after == $before ) {
        print "After is before. Moving out of until because all files are there!\n";
    }
    else {
        print "After isn't before.\n";
        my $before = $after;#set $before to be the new value after the update
        my $after = 0; #this will be updated in the next update
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```

When I run this, it claims that it is setting $before to $after in the `else{}`, but, in fact, $before remains 10, as it was set to before, and the program loops endlessly.

The script runs correctly when I remove the `my`s from inside `else{}`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $after = 0;
my $before ="10";

until( $before == $after ) {
    #check again, which changes the value of $after.
    #Now....
    $after = "20"; 

    if($after == $before) {
        print "After is before. Moving out of until because all files are there!\n";
    }
    else {
        print "After isn't before.\n";
        $before = $after;#set $before to be the new value after the update
        $after = 0; #this will be updated in the next update
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```

Does this mean that `$before` defined as 'my $before' within the else is not the same variable as '$before' defined above it?

Comment: It's a terrible idea to use `$a` and `$b for variable names

Comment: `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: What is `&update_a` in your code?

Comment: There's no obvious problem with the code you've shown, so I'll guess that the problem is in the code you didn't show.  If you can't come up with a runnable example that exhibits the problem, we probably can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write code, ***ALWAYS INDENT CORRECTLY***. It's difficult to see how the code executes, and it also can hide errors when code is poorly indented. Also, always use white space and don't double up statements. 90% of programming is maintenance, so what little extra typing you do to make your code easy to understand saves a ton of time in maintaining it.

I've reinvented your code, so I could read it.

---

When you use `my` to declare a variable, you are declaring it as a *lexically scoped*. What this means is that it is defined in a limited context. This is *ususally* a good thing. It means variables disappear when you no longer need them. However, it also means that variables disappear when you need them.

`my` variables live in the *block* where they're defined. If the are defined inside a `while/until` loop, they live within that while loop. Once you exit the `while`, they go bye-bye. Same thing with an `if` statement or a `for` loop. In fact, if you just put curly braces, the `my` variable, if defined in those curly braces will lose it's definition once outside:

```
{
    my $foo = "bar";
}
print "$foo\n";   # Whoops, $foo is undefined!
```

If you need a variable to live outside of the loop, it needs to be defined outside of that loop:

```
my $odd_count = 0;
for my $number ( @number_list ) {
    if ( $number % 2 ) { 
        $odd_count++;
    }
}
print "There are $odd_count numbers in my list\n";
```

You can also end up *redefining* a variable if you redeclare it with `my`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $foo = "bar";
{    # New block!
     say "Initial value of \$foo: $foo";
     my $foo = "foo";   # Using "my" on $foo
     say "Changed value of \$foo: $foo";
}
say "Final value of \$foo: $foo";
```

If you run this, you'll get:

```
Initial value of $foo: bar
Changed value of $foo: foo
Final value of $foo: bar
```

That's because you've redeclared `$foo` inside the block, so you now have a new variable `$foo` that will *cover* the old value of `$foo` until the block ends. Once the block ends, `the old`$foo` variable is back, with its old value:

```
my $foo = "bar";
{    # New block!
     say "Initial value of \$foo: $foo";
     $foo = "foo";   # No "my" on $foo
     say "Changed value of \$foo: $foo";
}
say "Final value of \$foo: $foo";
```

If you run this, you'll get:

```
Initial value of $foo: bar
Changed value of $foo: foo
Final value of $foo: foo
```

In this case, I removed the `my`. Now when I say `$foo = "foo";`, I'm using the same `$foo` I defined outside the block, so once I leave the block, `$foo` will still have its old value.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear and comprehensive explanation (and the advice on formatting)! I've been having these issue across several scripts, and I can't tell you how many headaches you've just saved me.